# Login mysql_num_rows Error

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my Check Login file... Its shows an error: 
Call to undefined function mysql_num_row()
Whats the problem?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
```

Comment: check what you get when you echo $sql;

Comment: try `$count=mysql_affected_rows();`

Comment: mysqli_query($result) don work!.......                                       
while mysql_query($result) works well!.......                           
mysql_affected_rows() also do not work! :\

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
 Call to undefined function mysql_num_row()
```

Means that you are using `mysql_num_row()` when you should be using `mysql_num_rows()`. Note the **s** at the end.

Comment: I tried..but then it shows error with mysql_num_rows()

Answer (score 0):

`Call to undefined function mysql_num_row()` this shows you have a typo:

Change `mysql_num_row()` to `mysql_num_rows()`

You should also change your MySQL to MySQLi or PDO as MySQL is depreciated as of PHP 5.5.

Example of MySQLi usage from your example:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: not when he has mysql_connect and mysql_select_db somewhere else in his scripts. Unless you can provide full-working solution, this is not valid code and will not work.

Comment: It's irrelevant when I am merely showing him an example of MySQLi. If he were to implement MySQLi instead of MySQL throughout his scripts as I suggested then why would the connection var be excluded?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\checklogin.php on line 8
 Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\checklogin.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

As said your mysql_error you use mysql_num_row() instead mysql_num_rows(), but on your code I see mysql_num_rows(). Can you check it?

In general, I would advise you to use [PDO extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql, because [mysql](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect) will be removed in the future version of PHP.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
```

Use this code can be unsafe for security reasons, depending on what type of validation pass these variables.
If you'll use PDO you can do the same code as most safety case:

```
// Initialize the database connection
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$your_hostname.';dbname=.'$your_db, $user, $pass, 
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
);
$sql="SELECT count(username) FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=:myusername and password=:mypassword";

// Create prepared statement
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindParam(':myusername', $myusername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindParam(':mypassword', $mypassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();

if($stm->fetchColumn()){
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
```

Comment: its quiet complicated :\

Comment: it is better to learn to properly than to relearn, although if this is not your specialty, then of course it is not necessary to hammer head

Comment: I say its better to learn alphabet.. before jumping on essays :D :P

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use mysqli ext :

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: He can't use that as it expects `mysqli_result` when the user has `mysql_result` object.